# Как заменить один uic на другой?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, uic

Есть код:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import uic from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton


class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
        uic.loadUi("win1.ui", self)

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 300)
        self.btn = QPushButton('Кнопка', self)
        self.btn.resize(100, 100)
        self.btn.move(100, 100)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.c)    

    def c(self):
        uic.loadUi("win2.ui", self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

---

Также есть два `uic` файла: **win1.uic** и **win2.uic**.
Нужно, чтобы по нажатию кнопки `btn` содержимое окна менялось с `win1` на `win2`. 
Если просто загружаю `win2`, то приложение вылетает.

Как это исправить?
Заранее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import uic 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, \
    QPushButton, QWidget, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


def screen(ui):
    window = uic.loadUi(ui)                     
    return window
    

class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.centralwidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget) 
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget) 
        
        self.initUI()
        
        self.window_1 = screen('win1.ui')      
        self.window_2 = screen('win2.ui')      
        self.window_2.hide()
        self.layout.insertWidget(0, self.window_1) 
        self.layout.insertWidget(0, self.window_2)
        self.flag = True

    def initUI(self):
        self.btn = QPushButton('Кнопка', self)
        self.btn.setFixedSize(100, 100)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.window_update) 
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter | Qt.AlignBottom)      

    def window_update(self):
        if self.flag:
             self.window_2.show()
             self.window_1.hide()
        else:
             self.window_1.show() 
             self.window_2.hide()
            
        self.flag = not self.flag
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.resize(500, 550)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо тебе огромное!! Очень выручил!

Comment: @CATpython пожалуйста.

Comment: Возник вопрос: а что делает строчка "self.layout.addWidget(self.btn, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter | Qt.AlignBottom)". И за что отвечает QVBoxLayout?

Comment: @CATpython https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html  Если у вас возникают другие проблемы - задайте новый вопрос.

Comment: Ок, спасибо.///